# WebdriverIO: Dot ('.') is not recognized as an internal, or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, webdriver-io

I have been facing this error when configuring the WebdriverIO **[test-runner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html)**:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

The command given on the WebdriverIO site is: `./node_modules/.bin/wdio --help`, but running it in `cmd` shows the previously mentioned error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

The command on the website is for Linux (or mac) environment.

It looks like you're on Windows so you have to type `node_modules\.bin\wdio --help`

Comment: Which means the following command would do the things for windows right **node_modules\.bin\wdio config -y**